# What is the difference between a marcato and an accent?

Tags: notation, technique, terminology, accent

I hear a few people refer to what looks like an accent as a marcato. Is a marcato a different name for accent, or is it a different way of playing the accent?

Comment: Be aware that marcato can also be used as a musical direction that applies to several notes at once.

Comment: Regarding any difference in execution, it would be helpful to know the instrument involved. Winds, strings (plucked vs. bowed), and percussion would all use different techniques.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We were talking about this just a couple weeks ago in band.  An accent (the one that looks like a greater-than sign) we played with a bell tone in mind.  Hit it hard and then back off slightly (it does, after all, look like a small decrescendo mark.)  The marcato (the one that looks like a pointy hat) meant to hit it hard (and perhaps even slightly harder than an accent) but without the nuance of backing off.  Others may interpret them differently.

Answer (score 2):

It is correct that the sign > is called accent, but it seems like some might call it marcato. But another symbol for an accentuated note the sign ^ seems to be called marcato by others.
Personally I am used to using the term marcato as the whole word "*marcato*" or "*marc.*" printed in the sheet music to indicate that a passage should be played marcato.

Besides the signs > and ^ there are also ***sfz*** and ***fz***. Forthermore there is ***fp*** which is typical on a sustained note that is supposed to start with a very strong attack then continuing softly. There are other articulation signs that can give some kind of accentuation, like a staccato dot or a tenuto dash but the term "articulation" might fit better on those than "accentuation".

How to perform them can depend a lot of the style of the music, the composer, tradition and interpretation.

Answer (score 0):

How to execute an accent is the question? It is quite common to say 'hit it hard' but the result is a hard articulation which transfers from tongue to throat resulting in a distorted and brittle sound. A good analogy is making a fast descrescendo using the wind, wind being the focus of the articulation. This will result in a clearer non-distorted accent, larger full fledged sound, relaxed tongue and throat, so clarity and intonation is preserved. Remember: the function of the tongue (among other things) is the restriction/resistance to sound. Thus, a kind of reverse psychology will result in a much enhanced player/ensemble when performing the accent.

Comment: Hi Randall. Welcome to the site. Just a quick note suggesting you take a second look at the question, which is asking about the difference between the terms and symbols for "marcato" and "accent". You've posted a nice description of executing an accent on a wind instrument, so perhaps supplementing it with a description of marcato execution.